# Logically sorting a list of lists (partially ordered set -> topological sort)

Tags: python

**Edit**
The accepted answer works for sets that satisfy the requirements of a [strict partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders), so that a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) can be constructed:

- irreflexivity `not a < a`: the list does not contain items like `['a','a']`
- transitivity `if a < b and b < c then a < c`: the list does not contain items like `['a','b'],['b','c'],['c','a']`
- asymmetry`if a < b then not b < a`: the list does not contain items like `['a','b'],['b','a']`

---

Take this list of lists:
`[['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ]`
and flatten it to a single list, sorted depending on a value's neighbor(s):

- the first sublist tells you that b comes before c
- then a before c
- b before a
- and finally d after c

The overall ordering between sublists is consistent, meaning there won't be sublists like these: `['b','c'],['c','b']`. 
So the result should be: `['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']`

After a (long) while I came up with this ugly mess:

```
def get_order(_list):
    order = _list[0]
    for sublist in _list[1:]:
        if not sublist:
            continue
        if len(sublist) == 1:
            if sublist[0] not in order:
                order.append(sublist[0])
            continue
        new_order = order.copy()
        for index, value in enumerate(sublist):
            inserted = False
            new_order_index = None
            if value in new_order:
                new_order_index = new_order.index(value)
                new_order.remove(value)
            for previous_value in sublist[:index][::-1]:
                if previous_value in new_order:
                    insert_index = new_order.index(previous_value) + 1
                    print('inserting', value, 'at position', insert_index, 'after', previous_value)
                    new_order.insert(insert_index, value)
                    inserted = True
                    break
            if inserted:
                continue
            for next_value in sublist[index:]:
                if next_value in new_order:
                    insert_index = new_order.index(next_value)
                    print('inserting', value, 'at position', insert_index, 'before', next_value)
                    new_order.insert(insert_index, value)
                    inserted = True
                    break
            if inserted:
                continue
            if new_order_index is None:
                print('appending', value)
                new_order.append(value)
            else:
                print('leaving', value, 'at position', new_order_index)
                new_order.insert(new_order_index, value)
        order = new_order
    return order

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ]
    order = get_order(test_list)
    #>>> inserting a at position 1 before c
    #>>> inserting c at position 2 after a
    #>>> inserting d at position 3 after c
    #>>> inserting a at position 1 before c
    #>>> inserting c at position 2 after a
    #>>> inserting b at position 0 before a
    #>>> inserting a at position 1 after b
    print(order)
    #>>> ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

It *appears* to do exactly as expected, but it is far from efficient (or elegant for that matter).
Are there any algorithms that can sort like that?
Or are there some pythonic tricks that would make this more efficient?

---

Comment: Can there be cases like `[['b', 'c'], ['c', 'b']]`? If yes, how would the output be?

Comment: The concept you're looking for is "partial ordering".  A search on that term should bring you a lot of hits for precedence trees when there *is* no strict ordering, but will include the case where you *do* finish with such a list.

Comment: You're basically defining a poset https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set using these lists and then trying to perform a topological sort of that poset. The problem with this is that depending on the exact ordering you specify, there may be zero or many "correct" answers.  For instance, `[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']]` will have none and `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd'], ['c', 'd']]` could have abcd OR acbd because b, c are incomparable.  Further clarification is needed for these cases.

Comment: Austin and BowlingHawk95: I have edited my post. There can be no conflicts in the ordering between any sublists. Thank you for the pointers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing answers by nosklo and Ajax1234 both fail on an input of `[[1, 3], [3, 5], [5, 2], [2, 4]]`. The attempt in your question [fails](https://ideone.com/5Kz8mE) on an input of `[[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2]]`.

The correct approach is as described by BowlingHawk95: perform a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the directed acyclic graph induced by your input list.

We could implement our own topological sort, but it's safer to let an existing graph library handle it. For example, [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/):

```
from itertools import chain, tee

import networkx
import networkx.algorithms

# pairwise recipe from the itertools docs.
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def merge_ordering(sublists):
    # Make an iterator of graph edges for the new graph. Some edges may be repeated.
    # That's fine. NetworkX will ignore duplicates.
    edges = chain.from_iterable(map(pairwise, sublists))

    graph = networkx.DiGraph(edges)
    return list(networkx.algorithms.topological_sort(graph))
```

This produces correct output for the input in the question, the `[[1, 3], [3, 5], [5, 2], [2, 4]]` case the other answers failed on, and the `[[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2]]` case your attempt failed on:

```
>>> merge_ordering([[1, 3], [3, 5], [5, 2], [2, 4]])
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
>>> merge_ordering([['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd']])
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
>>> merge_ordering([[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2]])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

We can also write a version that raises an error if the input list doesn't uniquely determine the flattened form:

```
def merge_ordering_unique(sublists):
    # Make an iterator of graph edges for the new graph. Some edges may be repeated.
    # That's fine. NetworkX will ignore duplicates.
    edges = chain.from_iterable(map(pairwise, sublists))

    graph = networkx.DiGraph(edges)
    merged = list(networkx.algorithms.topological_sort(graph))

    for a, b in pairwise(merged):
        if not graph.has_edge(a, b):
            raise ValueError('Input has multiple possible topological orderings.')

    return merged
```

Demo:

```
>>> merge_ordering_unique([['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd']])
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
>>> merge_ordering_unique([[1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in merge_ordering_unique
ValueError: Input has multiple possible topological orderings.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a lookup function that determines if a particular value should be placed before or after another value:

```
d = [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd']]
flattened = {i for b in d for i in b}
def _lookup(a, b):
  _loc = [i for i in d if a in i and b in i]
  return True if not _loc else _loc[0].index(a) < _loc[0].index(b)

class T: 
  def __init__(self, _val):
    self.v = _val
  def __lt__(self, _n):
    return _lookup(self.v, _n.v)

final_result = [i.v for i in sorted(map(T, flattened))]
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

Using `[['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e']]`:

```
['b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: What if input = `d = [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'a'], ['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'e']]`

Comment: Oh this is very creative. I like that mapping of values to a helper object which ultimately dictates the ordering.